# Remove a value from comma separated string in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have done something like:

```
var a = "77,82,83";
foreach (var group in a.Split(','))
{
    a = group.Replace("83", string.Empty);
}
```

If i want to remove 83 but override last updated value and got output empty or remove value from that i passed to replace.

e.g `var a = 77,82,83`
want output like `77,82`

**Edit**:

"83" can be in any position.

Comment: Are you always wanting to remove the last item or might you want an output like "77,83" with the 82 removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want output as string you don't need to `Split`. Just get the [`LastIndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_) the `,` character and perform [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the variable:

```
var a = "77,82,83";
var newString = a.Substring(0, a.LastIndexOf(',')); // 77,82
```

If you are unsure if the string has at least one `,`, you can validate before performing a `Substring`:

```
var a = "77,82,83";
var lastIndex = a.LastIndexOf(',');

if (lastIndex > 0)
    var newString = a.Substring(0, lastIndex);
```

**Update**:

If you want to remove specific values from any position:

Split the `string` -> Remove the values using `Where` -> Join them with `,` separator

```
a = string.Join(",", a.Split(',').Where(i => i != "83"));
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7yYRMW)

Comment: Hello @adiga thanks . what if i this 83 is in between. ? like a = "77,83,82"   ?? then what i do ? i just want to remove the value that in anywhere in string.

Comment: @KajalSawant Updated for any position

Comment: Note: I just experienced that, if the string-to-remove has a leading or trailing space in the source string, it will not be removed i,e,

` string s = "66, 77, 88";
string a = string.Join(",", s.Split(',').Where(i => i != "77"));
// "77" will not be removed `

Answer (score 0):

You might need to clarify the question slightly but I think you're asking for the following:

```
var a = "72,82,83";
var group = a.Split(',').ToList();
int position = group.FindIndex(p => p.Contains("83"));
group.RemoveAt(position);
```

You can make the item you're looking for in the Contains query a parameter.

I think the problem you're having with your original code is that the `foreach` is a loop over each item in the array, so you're trying to remove "83" on each pass.